# Pasting more than one geometry at a time in Quick WKT plugin for QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, well-known-text, well-known-binary

I have a CSV of WKBs that I need to convert to WKT.

Can I paste them all into Quick WKT at the same time?

How do you break the spaces between geometries?

Page break, comma, semicolon, etc. do not seem to work.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, the WKT plugin allows you to do that.

Just paste each geometry in a new line:

[image]

Which loads all 3 geometries as 3 layers:

[image]

If you paste geometries of the same type, they will be created in the same layer, unless you check "Create a new layer for every geometry."

Comment: When I try this, I either get an error about uneven string length, or I only get the first geometry.

Comment: In that case, we do need more detail in your question. What versions are you using, some sample geometries, and the like.

Comment: I'm using the latest versions of QGIS and the Quick WKT plugin. This method works for WKT geometries but not geometries stored as WKB.